# Scheduling tasks on London time while system time is NY

Tags: java, datetime, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

Our system is configured with US/Eastern time and we have some scheduled tasks which must occur at specific Europe/London times.  How can we do this and make sure our tasks fire  correctly when daylight time changes take effect?

We use Quartz for scheduling.  Currently we schedule tasks using `SimpleTrigger`, and not `CronTrigger`.  The [docs](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/faq.html#FAQ-daylightSavings) indicate that CronTrigger should work - but I think this assumes the scheduled time and the system time are on the same time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CronTrigger` would indeed serve your purpose better, as you can use its `setTimeZone` method to define which timezone will be used when resolving the trigger's `CronExpression`. And no, the scheduled time and system time do not need to be on the same timezone. So, it should certainly work. (Of course, pay attention to the notes about daylight savings and crontriggers in the documentation you linked to.)

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if you can use CronTrigger to say "run this job every day at 14:00 London time"?  If the time is adjusted due to daylight savings time switches, is the job still correctly run 14:00 London time?

Comment: Yes, it should run correctly. The only situation where problems could arise would be if the job was supposed to run around the same time when the time switch becomes effective. That may cause a skip or a repeat, depending on whether time switch was forward or backward.

Answer (score 2):

`CronTrigger` should be fine so long as you build it using the right time zone - which you can ensure with [`CronScheduleBuilder.inTimeZone`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronScheduleBuilder.html#inTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29). At least that's my interpretation of the docs...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with SimpleTrigger, but you have to take care in constructing the date to use as the trigger's startTime property (build that date in the desired timezone).